# Method com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.isClosed()Z is abstract

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, tomcat8, connector-j

I'm trying to change the connection pool of my app, in order to use Tomcat's connection pool (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool) instead of "Apache Commons DBCP".

However, I'm getting this error when trying to connect to the DB:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.isClosed()Z is abstract
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
...
...
```

I've read in other links that normally this is a problem with the MySQL-JDBC driver version, however, I've just updated to the latest Connector/J version (mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar) but I'm still getting this error.

Here's how the connection pool is created:

First, this goes on the context.xml file in the META-INF directory of my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context>
<Resource
    name="rhwebDB"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    testWhileIdle="true"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    testOnReturn="false"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    validationInterval="30000"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
    maxActive="10"
    minIdle="5"
    maxIdle="10"
    maxWait="10000"
    initialSize="2"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    logAbandoned="true"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"              
    username="dbUser"
    password="dbPwd"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/rhweb2015"/>
</Context>
```

Then I have a DBUtil.class that all the other libraries use:

```
public class DBUtil {

    static Connection connection = null;
    static {
        try {
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/rhwebDB");
            connection = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("DBUtil.NamingException" + e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("DBUtil.SQLException" + e);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public static synchronized void closeConnection(Connection conn) {
        try {
            if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed())
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("Error closing the connection ! " + sqle);
        }

    }
}
```

And finally, all the other java libraries use the connection pool like this:

```
public boolean someFunction( String myValue ){
    Connection conn = null;
    boolean fRetVal = false;

    String query = "select something from anytable";

    try {
        conn = DBUtil.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( query );

        if ( rs.next() )
            fRetVal = true;

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

    } catch( SQLException ex ) {
            System.out.println(ex);
    }finally{
        DBUtil.closeConnection(conn);
    }

    return fRetVal;
}
```

Am I missing something? I don't get any errors when Tomcat starts.

JDK version: 8 (java version "1.8.0_111")
Tomcat version: 8.5.8
MySQL Server 5.6

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Your concept of how to use a connection pool is competely wrong. Get rid of your `DBUtil` class altogether, and specifically its static `Connection` object; use a *new* connection from the pool *every time one is requested*; and return it to the pool by closing it. You are keeping a dog and barking yourself.

Comment: if I get rid of DBUtil class, how will the connection pool be created? 
In that class it's specified where the connection pool info is defined:
DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/rhwebDB");

Comment: I mean, how do I get a new connection from the pool?, should I specify all the datasource code on every function that uses the connection pool? There's a lot of functions that uses it. I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: OK, see my answer.

Comment: The error itself means that you are using a very old version of the MySQL Connector/J driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all wrong. You are keeping a dog and barking yourself. You can't use static `Connections` in the first place, and in the second place using a static `Connection` defeats the entire purpose of using a connection pool. It should be more like this:

```
public class DBUtil {

    static DataSource ds;
    static {
        try {
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/rhwebDB");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("DBUtil.NamingException" + e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("DBUtil.SQLException" + e);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return ds.getConnection();
    }
}
```

and, using try-with-resources to close everything:

```
public boolean someFunction( String myValue ){
    boolean fRetVal = false;

    String query = "select something from anytable";

    try (Connection conn = DBUtil.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( query )) {
        if ( rs.next() )
            fRetVal = true;
    } catch( SQLException ex ) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    return fRetVal;
}
```

E&OE

But note that you don't really need the `DBUtil` class at all. You can inject the `DataSource` anywhere you need it via an annotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!. It seems I can't think clear these days.
If you don't mind answering this as well, Why did you declare `static` the method that returns the connection?
    
`public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return ds.getConnection();
    }`

Comment: Because you did. There's no instance state, so why would you make it non-static? Alternatively, you could make the `DataSource` non-static, construct it in a constructor instead of a static initializer, and make `getConnection()` non-static, and then turn the whole thing into a singleton ... but I don't really see the point.